# Hiding a bad database schema behind neater domain POCOs

Tags: entity-framework, orm, poco, sql-view

I'm working on an application that interfaces with a slightly odd database. The design of this database is pretty bad; there are basically no foreign keys (although there are columns that reference other tables, they're not set as keys), columns are named very ambiguously, and the structure does not lend itself to the kind of logic I'm aiming to do (mostly, it forces joins for operations that should be simple, and leaves you trawling through needlessly massive tables for things that could have been split).

Unfortunately, I'm stuck with this database. It's being replicated off a third-party system, so I can't change the table structure or anything. I can add stored procedures and views, though.

In the application, I've come up with a set of classes that I can work with much more easily. I've got quite a bit of experience with Entity Framework, so I'm planning to use that. My initial hunch is that I can add views to the database that return things in the format of my classes, and then from there on out just pretend that they're tables. I've never tried anything like this before, though, and I'm not entirely sure how to proceed.

How can I use Entity Framework to map my classes to these views? Note that it kinda needs to be my POCO classes, rather than anything EF auto-generates - is there a way to tell EF to map existing classes?

Answer (score 1):

If you use code first then Entity Framework will generate `CreateTable` instructions in the migrations. To use a view instead, replace this code with your own Sql to generate the View. See the answer to this question: [Mapping Database Views to EF 5.0 Code First w/Migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862807/mapping-database-views-to-ef-5-0-code-first-w-migrations)

I would also [configure Entity Framework to use stored procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/dn468673.aspx). Then you can tailor the insert/update/delete sql to match the underlying tables. Again, you can do this by altering the sql that is generated for you in the migrations.

Comment: As I said, the database already exists and is being created from a third-party system, so I can't use Code First or Migrations.

Comment: You can use Code First and Migrations as long as you ensure that it only creates Views and Stored Procedures and you do that by by altering the code in the migrations as suggested in my answer