# How to select specific columns in Entity Framework in ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, entity-framework-6

I want to select specific columns like username, message and subject only from SQL Server Database in Entity Framework in ASP.NET. But my program returns all the columns from table `emailtable`.

Here is my code:

```
kicsEntities db = new kicsEntities();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    emailtable et = new emailtable();

    string var = Session["username"].ToString();

    GridView1.DataSource = db.emailtables.Where(em => em.receiver == var).ToList(); 
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: You need to make a ViewModel class with properties you want, then continue your query with .Select(x=> new Vm(){...}).ToList()

Answer (score 2):

You can use projection.  For example, create a view model (c# class) called MyClass and declare the properties you require from the database object.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}
```

Now using Linq you can request only the properties you require from the database table

```
db.TableName.Select(m => new MyClass 
{
    Username = m.Username,
    Message = m.Message,
    Subject = m.Subject
});
```

You can now bind the returned collection as your gridview's datasource with the added benefit of having a strongly typed control.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a view to your database model and have it included only those columns that you would want to retrieve. If your approach is code-first, you can add/map the view as described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862807/mapping-database-views-to-ef-5-0-code-first-w-migrations/20887064#20887064).