# Database.SqlQuery doesn't return any result

Tags: c#, entity-framework, view

I create a view as you can see :

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ViewMTO]
AS
    SELECT        
        dbo.Lines.Unit, dbo.Lines.LineNumber, dbo.Lines.DocumentNumber, 
        dbo.BaseMaterials.Name AS MaterialName, 
        dbo.MaterialDescriptions.Name AS MaterialDescription, 
        dbo.MaterialDescriptions.Description, 
        dbo.MaterialScopes.ScopeName, dbo.MaterialScopeObjectNames.ObjectName, 
        dbo.MaterialDescriptions.Size1, dbo.MaterialDescriptions.Size2, 
        dbo.MaterialDescriptions.ItemCode, dbo.Materials.Quantity, 
        dbo.Materials.Discipline
    FROM            
        dbo.Materials 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Lines ON dbo.Materials.LineId = dbo.Lines.Id 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.BaseMaterials ON dbo.Lines.BaseMaterialId = dbo.BaseMaterials.Id 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.MaterialDescriptions ON dbo.Materials.MaterialDescriptionId = dbo.MaterialDescriptions.Id 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.MaterialScopes ON dbo.MaterialDescriptions.MaterialScopeId = dbo.MaterialScopes.Id 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.MaterialScopeObjectNames ON dbo.MaterialDescriptions.MaterialScopeObjectId = dbo.MaterialScopeObjectNames.Id
```

In my application I want to call it as you can see :

```
public List<DAViewMTO> ViewMTOByDetail()
{
    List<DAViewMTO> lst = new List<DAViewMTO>();
    lst = _ctx.Database.SqlQuery<DAViewMTO>("SELECT * FROM [SPMS2].[dbo].ViewMTO").ToList();
    return lst;
}
```

But this query never returns any result. I put a break point in this function and the break point never passes this line:

```
 lst = _ctx.Database.SqlQuery<DAViewMTO>("SELECT * FROM [SPMS2].[dbo].ViewMTO").ToList();
```

I have another views with another functions that have this structure and don't have any problem.When i execute my query directly in the SQL it doesn't have any problems.

I call it in the UI:

```
private void frmViewMaterialTakeOf_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        splashScreenManager1.ShowWaitForm();
        gridControl.DataSource = new BindingList<DAViewMTO>(_materialRepository.ViewMTOByDetail()) { AllowNew = true };
        splashScreenManager1.CloseWaitForm();

    }
```

Comment: Why do you specify the name of the database `[SPMS2]` in your query  ? Shouldn't that be the role of the connection string ? Second, if the function `ViewMTOByDetail` never gets called, then you need to show where you're calling it.

Comment: SPMS2 is the name of database

Comment: I know it is the name of the database. But you don't need it. You already specify it in the connection string. Why are you writing a raw SQL query ? You can map the view directly through Entity Framework and then call it like this: `_ctx.ViewMTO.ToList();` Just like you map any other physical table.

Comment: @user3185569 i am using entity code first so how can i call this view like this :_ctx.ViewMTO.ToList();

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862807/mapping-database-views-to-ef-5-0-code-first-w-migrations

Comment: @user3185569 When i change the query i mean SELECT * FROM [SPMS2].[dbo].ViewMTO the result returned but the problem comes from the view why

Comment: Try using `SELECT * FROM [dbo].ViewMTO` and try running your view query directly inside SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid object name 'dbo.ViewMTO'.

Comment: You have a problem in your connecting string. You're connecting to a database other than the database where you created your view. Check the connection string you're passing to your context of present in app.config.

Comment: @EhsanAkbar 1) Enable all exception in your  VS debugger and remove just my code in VS Options and check if any exception is thrown behind the scenes. 2) When you excute "SELECT * FROM [SPMS2].[dbo].ViewMTO" in SSM tool you get the view results?

Comment: @BassamAlugili yes it works in my ssm

Comment: lst = _ctx.Database.SqlQuery<DAViewMTO>("SELECT * FROM [SPMS2].[dbo].ViewMTO").ToList();
   Can you enable all exceptions? maybe you can find any usefull error message which is not redirected to your code.

Comment: @BassamAlugili ok let me to enable my exceptions\

Comment: Yes it works ,the problem was casting

Comment: @BassamAlugili why the VS  doesn't return the error without  try catch !?

Comment: maybe this is a first chance exception just post the error message and lets see