# Code First EF, map entity to view - Automatic migration was not applied because it would result in data loss

Tags: entity-framework, view, ef-code-first

I created an entity and mapped to a view.
Now the migration script is applied correctly, everything works fine, but there this error after `Update-Database` and each time after run `Update-Database` the same error occurs:

(I don't want to disable AutomaticMigration)

> Automatic migration was not applied because it would result in data
>   loss. Set AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed to 'true' on your
>   DbMigrationsConfiguration....

The AutomaticMigration generates this:

```
IF object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.MyView_dbo.Table2_column1FromView]', N'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].MyView DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.MyView_dbo.Table2_column1FromView]
    // (.. more similar lines...)
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = N'IX_column2FromView' AND object_id = object_id(N'[dbo].[MyView]', N'U'))
    DROP INDEX [IX_column2FromView] ON [dbo].[MyView]
    // (.. more similar lines...)
```

MyView:

```
public class MyView
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? Column1FromView { get; set; }

    public int? Column2FromView { get; set; }

    .....
}
```

And in the DbContext:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        ...

        modelBuilder.Entity<MyView>().ToTable("MyView");
    }
```

The Migration:

```
public partial class CreateMyView : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Sql(@"CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MyView] 
              AS SELECT .... FROM   dbo.MyTable   
              GO ");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
       Sql("DROP VIEW [dbo].[MyView];");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of the hacks to use views with EF code first you have to tell EF to create a real table in your DbContext mappings:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyView>().ToTable("MyView");
```

You are supposed to create an explicit migration after that to remove that temporary table and keep only the view.

So it seems that you are still using a real table. A couple of things you could try:

- Temporarily enable the data loss by setting `AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed` to true in the MigrationsConfiguration file. Run your migration and then set that value to false again (to prevent unnoticed data loss in the future).
- Really removing the table with an explicit migration as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20887064/1182515).

Answer (score 0):

If you add a property to your model class, in your case its `Column2FromView` . EF creates your column with no error.
But if you try to remove the created column from your table it warns you about if that column has data or not.
You should simply force it by `update-database -force` command.