# SQL View with Entity Framework 5 Code First Migration

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I am using Migrations, but I had to manually add a SQL View as it pulls from other tables that aren't going to be mapped in my context/repository.

However, now it thinks the context has changed. I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383459/entity-framework-code-first-and-view-mapping) that asks the same question, but it doesn't solve the problem. I can't just create the view model from existing entities.

Is there another way? I wouldn't mind using SqlQuery if I could something like:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<ContactsByPartyCampaignViewModel>("myView")
```

Do I need to drop migrations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

Add this : `Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);`

in Global.asax under `Application_Start()` will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I am just using a console app and test project right now, so I don't have a global.asax file. I placed it in the modelbuilder override and that worked. It does this exactly do? It skips looking for migrations? When I run Add-Migration, it still picks it up.

Comment: Would be nice if you mentioned what this was actually doing so that others could make informed decisions on whether this was right for them.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul :We use it to set the `DbInitialization` strategy go null as opposed to letting code first just use the default `“CreateDatabaseWhenNotExist”,` or using one of the others
 e.g. `“DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges”` or even a custom strategy that you’ve created based on one of the built in strategies.
You typically set `DbInitialization` strategies at application startup, for example in `global.asax` for web apps and you do the same even if you are setting it to null.