# How to map exisiting sql server view with EF code first

Tags: entity-framework

i am fairly new in EF and learning EF code first. i am looking for a knowledge to map exisiting sql server view with EF code first. i have map my view with POCO but getting the below error.

when i try to fetch data from view then got the below error thrown

> Additional information: The model backing the 'TestDBContext' context
>   has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First
>   Migrations to update the database

### my full code as follow

```
public class TestDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public TestDBContext()
            : base("name=TestDBContext")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new vwCustomerConfiguration());
        }

        public DbSet<vwCustomer> vwCustomer { get; set; }
    }

public class vwCustomerConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<vwCustomer>
{
    public vwCustomerConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.CustomerID);
        this.ToTable("vwCustomer");
    }
}

      public class vwCustomer
        {
            public int CustomerID { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }

        }
```

### this way i am trying to load data.

```
    using (var db = new TestDBContext())
    {
        var listMyViews = db.vwCustomer.ToList();
    }
```

guide me what i am missing in code for which error is throwing. thanks

### UPDATE1

When i issue Add-Migration "My_vwCustomer" then i saw new migration code added as below one. it seems there is no migration is pending.

```
   public partial class My_vwCustomer : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.vwCustomers",
                c => new
                    {
                        CustomerID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        FirstName = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.CustomerID);

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropTable("dbo.vwCustomers");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I solved migration generation problem. [See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62287959/5200896)

Comment: To prevent migration from being added for your view you can use `.ToView()` instead of `.ToTable()` within the DbContext, change `this.ToTable("vwCustomer");` to  `this.ToView("vwCustomer");` in your code

Answer (score 10):

**OP's Feedback :**

> When i generate the view with ADO.Net Entity model wizard then
> everything works fine.

You can do it as shown below.

**Note :** I have picked the 1 to 4 from [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461265/how-to-use-views-in-code-first-entity-framework).

1. Create a POCO class for the view; for example `FooView`
2. Add the `DbSet` property in the `DbContext` class
3. Use a `FooViewConfiguration` file to set a different name for the view
   (using `ToTable("Foo")`; in the constructor) or to set particular
   properties

   ```
   public class FooViewConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<FooView>      
   {
      public FooViewConfiguration()
      {
          this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
          this.ToTable("myView");
      }
   }
   ```
4. Add the FooViewConfiguration file to the modelBuilder, for example
   ovveriding the OnModelCreating method of the Context:

   ```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FooViewConfiguration ());
   }
   ```
5. According to the above configuration,now your table is
   `this.ToTable("myView");`.In other words `myView`.

   Here is the `EF query` to retrieve `all the data` on the `myView` table.

   `var listMyViews = yourDbContext.myView.ToList()`

***Your projection may be like this :***

```
var query = yourDbContext.myView
    .Select(v=> new
    {
        ID = v.ID,
        EmpName = v.EmpName,
        Salary = v.Salary 
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: can u plzz post a small but complete sample code for this scenario.

Comment: see my updated post. i am getting error when run the code. see my full code. thanks

Comment: why do i need to migrate because i have a view exist in db table. migrate create db object but what if the object already exist ?

Comment: Yes,you're right.No need to do that.I have removed it.can you tell me what is your DB view's name ?

Comment: my db view name is vwCustomer.

Comment: OK then it should be mapped automatically.do you have any other pending migrations ? you can see it by just run `PM> Add-Migration "My_Tables"` command.

Comment: which line i need to remove. this line is in my dbcontext class `public DbSet<vwCustomer> vwCustomer { get; set; }`

Comment: When i generate the view with ADO.Net Entity model wizard then everything works fine. just do not understand what was the problem. many thanks for your help.

Comment: Great.I have updated the above post with your feedback.if you need to add more please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Configure view as a table and use this custom generator to prevent migration generation for tables marked as views

```
public class SkipViewGenerator: CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator
{
    protected override void Generate(CreateTableOperation operation, IndentedTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (!IsView(operation.Name))
            base.Generate(operation, writer);
    }

    protected override void Generate(RenameTableOperation operation, IndentedTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (!IsView(operation.Name))
            base.Generate(operation, writer);
    }

    protected override void Generate(MoveTableOperation operation, IndentedTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (!IsView(operation.Name))
            base.Generate(operation, writer);
    }

    protected override void Generate(DropTableOperation operation, IndentedTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (!IsView(operation.Name))
            base.Generate(operation, writer);
    }

    protected override void Generate(AddColumnOperation operation, IndentedTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (!IsView(operation.Table))
            base.Generate(operation, writer);
    }

    protected override void Generate(DropColumnOperation operation, IndentedTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (!IsView(operation.Table))
            base.Generate(operation, writer);
    }

    protected override void Generate(DropPrimaryKeyOperation operation, IndentedTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (!IsView(operation.Table))
            base.Generate(operation, writer);
    }

    protected override void Generate(AlterColumnOperation operation, IndentedTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (!IsView(operation.Table))
            base.Generate(operation, writer);
    }

    protected override void Generate(AddPrimaryKeyOperation operation, IndentedTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (!IsView(operation.Table))
            base.Generate(operation, writer);
    }

    protected override void Generate(AlterTableOperation operation, IndentedTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (!IsView(operation.Name))
            base.Generate(operation, writer);
    }

    protected override void Generate(CreateIndexOperation operation, IndentedTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (!IsView(operation.Name))
            base.Generate(operation, writer);
    }

    protected override void Generate(DropIndexOperation operation, IndentedTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (!IsView(operation.Name))
            base.Generate(operation, writer);
    }

    private bool IsView(string tableNameWithSchemaName)
    {
        var tableName = DatabaseName.Parse(tableNameWithSchemaName).Name;
        var schemaName = DatabaseName.Parse(tableNameWithSchemaName).Schema;
        return schemaName.Contains("View");
    }
}
```

Usage example

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        CodeGenerator = new SkipViewGenerator();
    }

    protected override void Seed(MyDbContextcontext)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data.
    }
}
```

`DatabaseName.Parse` implementatnion you can get from Github [sources](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/blob/02104044fae2aca5d3a1f50f55f4af940a3c64a8/src/Common/DatabaseName.cs)